# My app(game) is detected as Trojan in MI phone while installing, Mi Phones detect my app as Trojan

Tags: android, cocos2d-x, android-install-apk, cocoscreator, redmi-permission

I have developed a game using cocos2d and it is on my personal website. When I install it on my Mi phones, during installation it shows me Trojan error with ignore button. But on other phone it shows nothing. Why it detects my app as a Trojan on MI Phones only. Please suggest some solution to remove this warning.
Please help.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I reported my issue to Avast.
[https://www.avast.com/false-positive-file-form.php]
 for false positive, and now my app did't give Trojan error/warning.

Comment: Why does it happen?